# Update from 14.04 to 16.04.3 interrupted due to power disconnection

Tags: 16.04, software-installation

I was trying to update my computer but I have a problem with my charger. So, halfway through the Ubuntu update from 14.04 to 16.04.3, there was a contact problem(the charger got disconnected) and it halted. Now the screen shows up black with this;
Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS *my name* tty1
 *name again* login:_
What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

It is showing the terminal, login with your username and password from the terminal and run same upgrade command

> sudo do-release-upgrade

to continue your upgrade.
This should work fine